# Hardware Security Module (HSM)

Tags: private-key, fips-140-2

Looking to purchase an HSM to manage private keys, and price/scalability-price is one of my main concerns. It does need to be FIPS 140-2, level 3 certified (or compliant at least) and it must be rackmountable. I have been looking at the Utimaco SafeGaurd SE and the ARX PrivateServer. Any suggestions on any other vendors that may have an appliance priced between 10-20k?

Comment: ActiveX, are you talking about asymmetric key pairs (public private) as in rsa? Or more as in SQL Server?

Answer (score 2):

The nShield line from Thales might have some options in your price range.

Answer (score 2):

Safenet Luna HSM from Gemalto is also a good product. FIPS 140-2 level 3 certified, as you requested. And most important, it supports other EC curves than those validated by NIST. For instance BrainPool curves, much more secure than NIST ones.